# MySQL count records from 4 tables

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I have 4 tables.

Table 1: articles (has some products)

Table 2: companies (has some companies ex. Mitsubishi, Haier etc)

Table 3: article_categories (has some categories ids connected with each product)

Table 4: article_company (has some companies ids connected with each product)

I have created the following sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a3b8d7/15

I want to count the products for each company.

```
   SELECT comp.CompanyID,comp.title,comp.status,count(aco.ArticleID) as count_articles 
   FROM companies comp 
   inner join article_company aco on aco.CompanyID=comp.CompanyID 
   inner join articles art on art.ArticleID=aco.ArticleID 
   inner join article_category ac on ac.ArticleID=aco.ArticleID 
   where comp.status = 1
   AND ac.CategoryID IN (245,253,259,261,521,263,743) 
   group by comp.CompanyID;
```

When i run the query i get 18 instead of 15.

If i execute the following query i get 15 records.

```
    SELECT comp.CompanyID,comp.title,comp.status,count(aco.ArticleID) as count_articles 
    FROM companies comp 
    inner join article_company aco on aco.CompanyID=comp.CompanyID 
    inner join articles art on art.ArticleID=aco.ArticleID 
    where comp.status = 1
    group by comp.CompanyID;
```

Any suggestions to change the first query in order to get the results from the second query?

Comment: Calculate `count(aco.ArticleID)` by this `aco` table only in the subquery, then join another tables to it.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have an example?

Comment: you'll still get 18, even if removing the part `AND ac.CategoryID IN (245,253,259,261,521,263,743) ` from the first query.

Comment: I have removed and thw join code. Check sql fiddle

Comment: *When i run the query i get 18 instead of 15.* You must get 14, not 15 or 18. Article 2877 is removed from the output because it is absent in `article_category` table.

Comment: Wow thank you @Akina. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT comp.CompanyID,
       comp.title,
       comp.status,
       count(DISTINCT aco.ArticleID) as count_distinct_articles
FROM companies comp 
inner join article_company aco on aco.CompanyID=comp.CompanyID 
inner join articles art on art.ArticleID=aco.ArticleID 
inner join article_category ac on ac.ArticleID=aco.ArticleID 
where comp.status = 1
AND ac.CategoryID IN (245,253,259,261,521,263,743) 
group by comp.CompanyID;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a3b8d7/27)

PS. Excess informational columns added - they are removed from the above query.